# "At the first" in the Bible

Tags: grammar, articles, religion

Why is the article *the* used in the following verse of the Bible?

> **At the first** God made the heaven and the earth.

To me *at first*, which according to OED means *at the beginning; in the initial stage or stages,* sounds more natural, unless there are specific grammatical delicacies that I am not aware of.

The passage is from an app on my iPhone called *My Bible Pro*.  It uses the King James Version of the Bible. Here are some screenshots.

[image] [image]

Comment: The app should tell you which version it is.

Comment: Well, according to the Google search that I just performed, Genesis 1:1 (KJV) starts with "In the beginning…"

Comment: @Mahnax - Google search?  Pfft!  I can confirm that the KJV Bible on my bookshelf begins Genesis 1:1 with the words "In the beginning ..."

Comment: @DavidWallace, I just posted the screenshots of the application.

Comment: @Mahnax, posted the screenshots.

Comment: This is definitely not the King James Version. It's the [Bible in Basic English](http://www.biblestudytools.com/bbe/genesis/1.html). Unfortunately, as Barrie has said, "At first" is far more idiomatic.

Comment: @Noah - 5 different people have now told you that this is NOT KJV.  Your app is wrong!

Comment: @Noah: Maybe you found a bug in your Bible app.  That translation is definitely from the BBE, not the KJV (see [translations in parallel](http://wwwdev.bibleshark.com/parallel_bible/WEB-KJV-BBE/Genesis/1/1/)).

Comment: @DavidWallace- I think so. Gotta talk to Tim Cook:)

Comment: Even though it's "broken English", the meaning of *at the first* is General Reference. Everything else about the question is Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers- You are probably right, and I don't begrudge you closing it.

Comment: There's a slider for intensity of KJV?

Comment: @cornbreadninja- I know, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidWallace We've got a copy, but at 2:00 AM I wasn't prepared to go get it from another floor of the house.

Comment: @cornbreadninja: That slider is awesome. It could be set up so that the far left is the BBE, the far right is the KJV, with stops of NLT, NIV, NAS, and NKJV in between.  Or even better, the more you slide it to the left, the more _thees_ and _thous_ get turned into _yous_ and _yours_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently, this is from the [**Basic English Bible** (BBE)](http://wwwdev.bibleshark.com/parallel_bible/WEB-KJV-BBE/Genesis/1/1/), not the more common King James Version.

If you find out how to switch your app to the King James Version, though, you're bound to find some linguistic oddities there, too.  Language has changed a lot over the past 300 to 400 years. Whether you read Shakespeare, Chaucer, or the King James Bible, you can't expect it to sound like contemporary English, which is why more contemporary translations have been written.

The [Basic English translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bible_in_Basic_English) may have some grammatical oddities as well, but for very different reasons.  It was deliberately written with very few basic words; it's essentially a ["Green Eggs and Ham"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Eggs_and_Ham#Lexicon) translation of the Scriptures.

As for why it was translated as *"At the first"* and not *"At first"*, I'm guessing they wanted to retain the three-word prepositional phrase construct, but for some reason thought *"In the beginning"* would be too difficult for its target audience.

Comment: I guess, I am using the right version. Maybe there is a problem with the app. Just switched it to BBE and apparently it uses the same text.

Comment: While you're debugging, go to the beginning of [Matthew](http://wwwdev.bibleshark.com/parallel_bible/WEB-KJV-BBE/matthew/1/).  If you see the word _begat_ over and over again, you know you've got your King James turned on.  ;^)

Answer (score 2):

*At the first God made the heaven and the earth* is most certainly not from the King James Bible, whose first words are *In the beginning God created the heaven and the earth*.

*At the first* is, however, found in these two subsequent passages in Genesis:

> Unto the place of the altar, which he had made there **at the first**: and
>   there Abram called on the name of the LORD. (13:4)
>
> And he called the name of that place Bethel: but the name of that city
>   was called Luz **at the first**. (28:19)

*At the first* might also be occasionally found elsewhere, but *at first* is more usual in most contexts.

Comment: I dont know, but the app says that it's the KJV. I just posted the screenshots.